# React Intercept component unmounting (Functional and Class Components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to **always** intercept when React unmounts a Component, no matter if that is a `Functional` or `Class` based component.

Here is my case:

```js
function observe(component) {
  const p = component.type.prototype;
  const delegate = p.componentWillUnmount || function noop() {};

  if(!delegate.__decorated) {
    p.componentWillUnmount = function() {
      console.log('I am going to be unmounted');

      return delegate.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    p.componentWillUnmount.__decorated = true;
  }

  return component;
}

class Comp extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const active = this.state && this.state.active;
    const toggle = () => this.setState({
      active: !active,
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
        <hr />
        {active && observe(<Comp />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, as you can easily see, I am able to hook on every time `<Comp />` gets unmounted. **That is just what I need**.

Things will dramatically change when that `<Comp />` is a functional component:

```
function observe(component) {
  const p = component.type.prototype;
  const delegate = p.componentWillUnmount || function noop() {};

  if(!delegate.__decorated) {
    p.componentWillUnmount = function() {
      console.log('I am going to be unmounted');

      return delegate.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    p.componentWillUnmount.__decorated = true;
  }

  return component;
}



function Comp() {

  return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
}


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const active = this.state && this.state.active;
    const toggle = () => this.setState({
      active: !active,
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
        <hr />
        {active && observe(<Comp />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, my question is:

#### How can I hook on functional components?

I can change approach (or use React internal Apis), I just need to always intercept changes on a component passed as arguments for `observe`.

Comment: If you need lifecycle methods, you should convert a functional component to a class. [ref](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#2ac5)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rkendall/visible-react, idk if the code works with functional components. faict, this is not feasible atm.

Comment: You can check out this library [react-functional-lifecycle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-functional-lifecycle), it basically adds lifecycle methods to function based class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. Functional components don't have lifecycles (yet).

Instead of messing with the functional component directly, why don't you just wrap the functional component in a class with a HOC. You could use recompose [`toClass`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#toclass) for this.

```
function observe(component) => {
  const classComponent = toClass(component):
  const p = classComponent.type.prototype;
  const delegate = p.componentWillUnmount || function noop() {};

  if(!delegate.__decorated) {
    p.componentWillUnmount = function() {
      console.log('I am going to be unmounted');

      return delegate.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    p.componentWillUnmount.__decorated = true;
  }

  return classComponent;
}
```

Or just copy the code from [here](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/toClass.js).

Comment: ^ this. Higher Order Components (HOC) are the way to go here.